# Make Java API Stream throwing exception

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object that contains a property which is a List of object that contains 2 string properties. My objective is to compare the keys of this map with another object which contains a String property.

To more clear my request contains map:

```
"documentType": "Document"
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "something",
    "value": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "name": "somethingElse",
    "value": "Someone"
  },
  {
    "name": "notADocumentColumn",
    "value": "shouldThrowException"
  },
  {
    "name": "notexistingcolumn",
    "value": "not a column"
  }
]
```

My sharePointDriveResponse contains columns:

```
"columns": [
     {
         "columnGroup": "Document",
         "description": "",
         "displayName": "something",
         "enforceUniqueValues": false,
         "hidden": false,
         "id": "8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "indexed": false,
         "name": "FileLeafRef",
         "readOnly": false,
         "required": true
    },
    {
         "columnGroup": "Billing or Whatever",
         "description": "",
         "displayName": "notADocumentColumn",
         "enforceUniqueValues": false,
         "hidden": false,
         "id": "3a6b296c-3f50-445c-a13f-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "indexed": false,
         "name": "ComplianceAssetId",
         "readOnly": true,
         "required": false,
         "text": {
             "allowMultipleLines": false,
             "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
             "linesForEditing": 0,
             "maxLength": 255
         }
     },
```

At this stage I implemented something that works fine:

```
List<String> check = sharePointDriveResponse.getColumns()
        .stream()
        .map(SharePointColumnsResponse::getDisplayName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .filter(request.getFields()::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(check.size() == request.getFields().size()) {
    System.out.println("It's OK !");
} else {
    throw new RequestException("One column provided doesn't exist");
}
```

My issue is the following:

1. Would it be possible to throw exception while streaming the data here ?

```
sharePointDriveResponse.getColumns()
            .stream()
            .map(SharePointColumnsResponse::getDisplayName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .filter(request.getFields()::containsKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
            // some operator here to throw exception
```

2. My second issue is that i also want to throw exception depending on the content type defined in the request and the content type allowed for the colum in the SharePointDriveResponse.

In the sample: I send a request to create a document and I pass a field that is not permitted for a Document, but allowed for another content type.

```
"columnGroup": "Billing or Whatever",
"description": "",
"displayName": "notADocumentColumn",
```

I'd also like to throw exception for this case.
I could also rebuild a similar stuff as I made previously, but I would loose efficiency for that simple task.

3. I also have another case where my "columnGroup" has a value that should be considered as accepted for all content types. Here is the basic partial implementation.

```
List<String> checkColumnsContentType = sharePointDriveResponse.getColumns()
        .stream()
        .map(SharePointColumnsResponse::getColumnGroup)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .filter(request.getFields()::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why do you do `.collect(toList()).stream()`? That does not make sense.

Comment: oups, you're right. I removed .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream() for the same result. I should sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for point 1 of my question. As it took some time to write the question, I let the question even after solving it.
Here is my implementation.

```
    sharePointDriveResponse.getColumns()
            .stream()
            .map(SharePointColumnsResponse::getDisplayName)
            .collect(toList())
            .stream()
            .filter(request.getFields()::containsKey)
            .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> {
                if (l.size() != request.getFields().size())
                    throw new RuntimeException("One column provided doesn't exist");
                return l;
            }));
```